# Is this resume sentence too much of a run-on?

Tags: phrase-request

I have a 'summary' at the top of my resume, and I really could use help wording this sentence. English isn't exactly my strongest point. Is this OK? If not, how can I improve it?

As an aside, I really care more about the structure and wording of this sentence and not so much about the content. I am happy with the content; I just want to make sure I am structuring the sentence correctly. The second sentence seems long winded and possibly a run-on; however, I don't know how else to word it.

> Software developer / analyst with 10 years’ experience as a LOB
>   application developer - mainly in financial services industry. A
>   stickler for high coding standards; excellent communication skills,
>   both written and verbal – a team player looking for a challenging,
>   rewarding work environment where I can continue to grow my skills and
>   add value to a successful team.

Comment: One tip: don't use acronyms/abbreviations in your summary. It's only one paragraph, and not the place to save characters.

Comment: "a team player looking for a challenging, rewarding work environment where I can continue to grow my skills and add value to a successful team." Everyone says that. Try to come up with something less generic, and more specific to you.

Comment: in THE financial services industry

Comment: This question should probably be migrated to Writers.se or English.se

Comment: Questions looking to reword a bit of text are off-topic on writers, I'm afraid.

Comment: Proofreading questions are also off-topic for ELL, unless the source of confusion is clearly specified. Because you have asked about the "run-on" feel of the sentences, I think that can be addressed here.

Answer (score 2):

> Software developer / analyst with 10 years’ experience as a LOB application developer - mainly in financial services industry. A stickler for high coding standards; excellent communication skills, both written and verbal – a team player looking for a challenging, rewarding work environment where I can continue to grow my skills and add value to a successful team.

I would say your biggest problem here is punctuation. The sentences read awkward mostly because of your slapdash use of the [dash](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/marks/dash.htm). Here are some pointers for you:

1) Don't put a space before and after a slash.

2) No apostrophe needed after *years*.

3) I think you've overused the dash. Your first dash could be a comma (or parentheses could be used, too). The second dash seems like it could just be the start of a new sentence.

4) I'd be careful about using the word *stickler*. It seems to clash with *team player*, as a *stickler* might be someone who is judgmental toward people who might not have the same standards as you.<sup>1</sup>

5) I don't see any need to specify *both written and verbal* when claiming that you have excellent communication skills. If you have to add that explicitly, then maybe your written skills aren't so excellent after all.

6) I don't like the way the word *skills* is applied to both your communication ability and your programming talent in the same paragraph.

So, having said all of that, here's my suggested rewrite:

> Software developer/analyst with 10 years experience as a LOB application developer (mostly in financial services). I am committed to high coding standards; I have excellent communication skills. I am a team player looking for a challenging, rewarding work environment where I can continue to grow my expertise and add value to a successful team.

I'm not saying this is perfect, but I'm saying it's an improvement, based on the comments I've made above.

---

<sup>1</sup> This hint is offered, not as a proofreading service (which would be off-topic for this site), but as an interesting aspect of English usage for the learner.